# Maximum likelihood estimates MATLAB

Tags: matlab, function, mle

Hi i would like to make a MLE estimate of my parameters using the built in functions in matlab. Here is what matlab says:

```
phat = mle(data,'distribution',dist)
```

I don't know how to use the vector "data". Suppouse I have  340 observations giving 0 , 120 observations at 2 , and 90 observations at 10

so how should the vector look like? [340,0,120,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,90] ? i doubt it. I just want to know the "structure" of the vector

Comment: You may want to look at the examples by matlab.

Comment: It would be a 1x550 array containing all observations.

Comment: @sobeck is right. The order of the data samples appear in the vector shouldn't matter. For your example: `data=[zeros(340,1);2+zeros(120,1);10+zeros(90,1)];`.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that `mle()` function can only handle scalar (1-D) data.

So if you want to estimate the class conditional distribution Pr[X = x|Y = 0], Pr[X = x|Y = 2] and Pr[X = x|Y = 10], then you need to split the sample data into three groups and call `mle()` three times. And for each call, you put all data points into one vector as the first argument.